# issue with CSS minus margin

Tags: html, css

i have use minus margin to place the navbar inside a div which has a class main..in small screen when i click on the navbar toggler icon it does not look good..because  i need to change the margin again...how can i solve this problem without using minus margin?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
        <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navDrop">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navDrop">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">ABOUT</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">SKILL</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">PORTFOLIO</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">TEAM</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">BLOG</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="main"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-    bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

here is output of my code:
https://codepen.io/Sakhawat5/pen/NzwQJz

Comment: I have trouble understanding your question/problem. Please make a working SO snippet here that reproduces your problem. And refactor your question a bit so it's more readable and understandable.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Sakhawat5/pen/NzwQJz

Answer (score 1):

**--Update--**

As I think your question is how to append the navbar class to the main div if the user has scrolled more then 50px. This is what could help you out.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 50) {
    // user scrolled 50 pixels or more;
    // do stuff for example:
     $('.navbar').appendTo('.main');
    // this will append the navbar to the main div, if you want other styling on the navbar aswell we can do the following:
     $('.navbar').addClass('.UserHasScrolled')  
    // now in you CSS set styling to .UserHasScrolled
  } else {
    // do things when user has NOT scrolled more then 50px
  }
});
```

Also make sure to include jQuery, this is possible, paste this beneath all other scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To your .UserHasScrolled class you can set something like this:

```
.UserHasScrolled {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     top: 0;
}
```

**--First answer--**

What you ask for is: @media screen and (max-width 767px) while the screen width has a lower size than 767px you can define an overwriting css style like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width 767px) {
   .navbar {
        margin-bottom: -336px;
   }
}
```

But this causes another problem, while the navbar is closed the main class will still have a margin of -336px and that's not what you want I guess.

To keep your navbar on top just set position to fixed:

```
.navbar {
     position: fixed;
     width: 90%;
     margin-left: 5%;
     margin-right: 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution:

```css
.top{
  height:50px;
  background:red;
}
.navbar{
  margin-left:20px;
  margin-right:20px;
}
.main{
  height:1500px;
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
      <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navDrop">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navDrop">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
             <a href="#" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
             <a href="#" class="nav-link">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
             <a href="#" class="nav-link">SKILL</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">PORTFOLIO</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">TEAM</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">BLOG</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">CONTACT</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
  </nav>
  </div>
</div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-    bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.but it does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The changes to your CSS as follows should fix the issue:

```
.navbar{
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

and if you don't want a fixed nav:

```
.navbar{
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: thanks...but that is not a proper solution for me. i want the navbar inside the .main div.when someone scroll the page , the navbar will fixed at top. you will find a sticky top bootstrap class in my html..the problem is how i put the navbar inside the .main div in different screen before scrolling the page?